# If any order preserving permutation submatrix of $A\otimes B$ belongs to $\{A,B\}$ does $A=B$?

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, matrices, permutations

Edited after the comment below: let $A$ and $B$ be two permutation matrices of size $n$. If any order preserving combination of $n$ rows and $n$ columns of $A\otimes B$ that is a permutation matrix is equal to $A$ or to $B$, does $A=B$? If yes, is it either the identity matrix or the one consisting only of $1$ on the secondary diagonal? Here $\otimes$ is the Kronecker product.

Comment: Which permutation matrix does *not* have that property?

Comment: Is this the Kronecker product?

Comment: Also, what you mean by $A \otimes B \in \{A, B\}$ ? The result of the product is one of the initial matrices? I don't get it.

Comment: No, the subject of "belongs to $\{A,B\}$" is not just $A\otimes B$ but the whole piece of sentence "any order preserving...of $A\otimes B$".